# Javascript XMLHttpRequest with Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to send some photos with `fetch` using `React JS` to `Django`. And then I want to save those photos to the database using Django.

The `React JS` function to handle sending photos is as follows:

```
handleAdd(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let data = this.state.data;
        let pictures = this.state.pictures;

        let body = new FormData();
        body.append('data', JSON.stringify(data));

        if (pictures.length > 0){
            _.each(pictures, (picture, i) => {
                body.append('pictures', picture);
            });
        }    

        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', `http://localhost:8000/master/api/add-inspection/`);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Token vEdD9t701LtDaCZYrSEutHKSNnAuUFAV");
        xhr.onload = e => {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    console.log("Status 200");
                } else {
                    console.log("Error");
                }
            }
        };
        xhr.onerror = e => {
            console.log("Error " + e);
        };
        xhr.send(body);
    }
```

And then Django.

In `settings.py` I have `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL`

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'master/static/master/img/inspection_pictures'),
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'master/static/master/img/inspection_pictures'),)
```

The `add_inspection` view is as follows:

```
@token_required
@transaction.atomic
def add_inspection(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = json.loads(request.POST.get('data'))
        pictures = request.FILES

        n_inspection = Inspection()
        n_inspection.user_id = data['user']['id']
        n_inspection.data = json.dumps(data)
        n_inspection.save()

        save_pictures(n_inspection, pictures)

        return HttpResponse("Its ok.", status=200)
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Something went wrong.", status=400)
```

Where the `save_pictures` function is as follows:

```
def save_pictures(inspection, pictures):

    print(pictures)  // Gives me <MultiValueDict: {'pictures': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: samsung-s8.png (image/png)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: Simulator Screen Shot 6 Jul 2017, 15.43.55.png (image/png)>]}>

    for picture in pictures['pictures']:
        n_picture = InspectionPictures()
        n_picture.inspection_id = inspection.id
        n_picture.picture = picture

        print(picture) // first iteration : b'\x89PNG\r\n'

        n_picture.save()
```

Thus, it seems that everything works perfect.

`InspectionPictures` model is as follows:

```
def inspection_picture_path(self, filename):
    return 'inspection_{0}/{1}'.format(self.inspection.id, filename)


class InspectionPictures(models.Model):
    inspection = models.ForeignKey(Inspection, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    picture = models.FileField(upload_to=inspection_picture_path, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Inspection-{}".format(self.inspection.id)
```

But when it needs to save the photo (`n_picture.save()`) I get **INTERNAL SERVER ERROR** (**AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute '_committed'**)

The whole error is as follows:

> Internal Server Error: /master/api/add-inspection/
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/boris/Projects/car_inspection/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
>       response = get_response(request)
>     File "/Users/boris/Projects/car_inspection/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
>       response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>     File "/Users/boris/Projects/car_inspection/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
>       response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>     File "/Users/boris/Projects/car_inspection/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
>       return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/Users/boris/Projects/car_inspection/car_inspection/api/authentication.py", line 71, in _view
>       return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 53, in inner
>       return func(*args, **kwds)
>     File "/Users/boris/Projects/car_inspection/car_inspection/api/views.py", line 29, in add_inspection
>       save_pictures(n_inspection, pictures)
>     File "/Users/boris/Projects/car_inspection/car_inspection/api/views.py", line 47, in save_pictures
>       n_picture.save()
>     File "/Users/boris/Projects/car_inspection/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 796, in save
>       force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
>     File "/Users/boris/Projects/car_inspection/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 824, in save_base
>       updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
>     File "/Users/boris/Projects/car_inspection/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 908, in _save_table
>       result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
>     File "/Users/boris/Projects/car_inspection/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 947, in _do_insert
>       using=using, raw=raw)
>     File "/Users/boris/Projects/car_inspection/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
>       return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/Users/boris/Projects/car_inspection/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1045, in _insert
>       return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
>     File "/Users/boris/Projects/car_inspection/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1053, in execute_sql
>       for sql, params in self.as_sql():
>     File "/Users/boris/Projects/car_inspection/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1006, in as_sql
>       for obj in self.query.objs
>     File "/Users/boris/Projects/car_inspection/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1006, in 
>       for obj in self.query.objs
>     File "/Users/boris/Projects/car_inspection/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1005, in 
>       [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
>     File "/Users/boris/Projects/car_inspection/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 955, in pre_save_val
>       return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)
>     File "/Users/boris/Projects/car_inspection/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 290, in pre_save
>       if file and not file._committed:
>   AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute '_committed'

Comment: There's quite a lot wrong here. Apart from anything else, you haven't saved the uploaded file contents anywhere, so this can't ever work. I suggest you read the [file uploads docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/) - as suggested there, the easiest way to do this is through a modelform.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Ok, could you tell me what is so much wrong here? I use React as frontend, I can't use modelform.

Comment: I did tell you. And I don't see how those things are in any way related. Of course you can use a modelform in conjunction with React.

Comment: @DanielRoseman No sir, you didn't. You said: "_There's quite a lot wrong here._". But then you said only one "wrong" thing: "_Apart from anything else, ..._". I know that it can be done and of course that I've tried to solve it reading the docs, but I could't apply it to my example and my problem and that is why I ask here for help. Putting the link to the docs and "_something is wrong here_" doesn't help me.